# Are shift-chains two-colorable?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-colouring, hypergraphs

For $A\subset [n]$ denote by $a_i$ the $i^{th}$ smallest element of $A$.

For two $k$-element sets, $A,B\subset [n]$, we say that $A\le B$ if $a_i\le b_i$ for every $i$.

A $k$-uniform hypergraph ${\mathcal H}\subset [n]$ is called a *shift-chain* if for any hyperedges, $A, B \in {\mathcal H}$, we have $A\le B$ or $B\le A$. (So a shift-chain has at most $k(n-k)+1$ hyperedges.)

We say that a hypergraph  ${\mathcal H}$ is two-colorable (or that it has Property B) if we can color its vertices with two colors such that no hyperedge is monochromatic.

Is it true that shift-chains are two-colorable if $k$ is large enough?

**Remarks.** I first posted this problem on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44312/do-shift-chain-have-property-b), but nobody commented on it.

The problem was investigated on the 1st Emlektabla Workshop for some partial results, see the [booklet](http://www.renyi.hu/~emlektab/index_booklet.html).

The question is motivated by decomposition of multiple coverings of the plane by translates of convex shapes, there are many open questions in this area. (For more, see my [PhD thesis](http://www.cs.elte.hu/~dom/cikkek/thesis.pdf).)

For $k=2$ there is a trivial counterexample: (12),(13),(23).

A very magical counterexample was given for $k=3$ by Radoslav Fulek with a computer program:

(123),(124),(125),(135),(145),(245),(345),(346),(347),(357),

(367),(467),(567),(568),(569),(579),(589),(689),(789).

If we allow the hypergraph to be the union of two shift-chains (with the same order), then there is a counterexample for any $k$.

**Update.** I have recently managed to show that more restricted version of shift-chains are two-colorable in [this preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.6900v1).

**Permanent bounty!** I'm happy to award a 500 bounty for a solution anytime!

Comment: Property B is more commonly called 2-colourability.

Comment: @Colin McQuillan: I thought so too because I had never heard the name “Property B”.  However, it seems that “Property B” is a common name in the literature.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_B

Comment: I stand corrected. I have deleted my wrong answer as well.

Answer (score 13):

This is not an answer.  What follows is a simple proof that the construction for *k*=3 is indeed a counterexample.  I think that the asker knows this proof, but I will post it anyway because the proof is nice and this might be useful when people consider the case of larger *k*.

It is easy to verify that it is a shift-chain.  Let’s show that it does not have Property B.

In fact, the subhypergraph {(123), (145), (245), (345), (346), (347), (357), (367), (467), (567), (568), (569), (789)} already fails to satisfy Property B.  To see this, suppose that this hypergraph has a 2-coloring and let *c*<sub>*i*</sub> be the color of the vertex *i*.  Look at three hyperedges (145), (245), (345).  If *c*<sub>4</sub>=*c*<sub>5</sub>, then all of 1, 2 and 3 must be the opposite color to *c*<sub>4</sub>, but this would give a monochromatic hyperedge (123).  Therefore, it must be the case that *c*<sub>4</sub>≠*c*<sub>5</sub>.  Similarly,

- *c*<sub>3</sub>≠*c*<sub>4</sub> by comparing the three hyperedges (345), (346), (347) and noticing a hyperedge (567).
- *c*<sub>6</sub>≠*c*<sub>7</sub> by comparing the three hyperedges (367), (467), (567) and noticing a hyperedge (345).
- *c*<sub>5</sub>≠*c*<sub>6</sub> by comparing the three hyperedges (567), (568), (569) and noticing a hyperedge (789).

Therefore, we have *c*<sub>3</sub>≠*c*<sub>4</sub>≠*c*<sub>5</sub>≠*c*<sub>6</sub>≠*c*<sub>7</sub>.  But this implies *c*<sub>3</sub>=*c*<sub>5</sub>=*c*<sub>7</sub>, making the hyperedge (357) monochromatic.  This contradicts the assumption of the 2-coloring.

Comment: Very nicely put, the asker likes your proof. Thanks for writing it down!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm missing something but I think there is a good lower bound with the probabilistic method:

If you color each vertex indepedently with probability $1/2$ for each color then your have a monochromatic edge with probability $2 \cdot (\dfrac{1}{2})^k = 2^{-k+1}$. With the [Lovasz local lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lov%C3%A1sz_local_lemma) you get that the shift-chain has property $B$ if
$$k(n-k)+1 \leq \dfrac{2^{k-1}}{e}-1.$$
I can't directly solve this inequality but if you have $k = \Omega(\log(n))$ then you get on the left hand side somethink like $n \log(n)$ and on the right hand side $n^c$ (so the inequality is true for $n$ large enough).

There is a [better bound](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/%28SICI%291098-2418%28200001%2916:1%3C4%3a%3aAID-RSA2%3E3.0.CO;2-2/abstract;jsessionid=92159B653F14ABD058BA1095562D614F.d01t02) of $O(\sqrt{k/\ln(k)} \cdot 2^k)$ on the number of edges for a $k$-uniform hypergraph so that the graph has property $B$.

Comment: You are right that if k is big enough compared to n, then the statement is true (e.g. k=n trivially). The problem is to prove that if k is bigger than some absolute constant, i.e. 4, then the statement is true for every n.

Comment: Ok, then just ignore the answer :)